# Variables de entorno en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy usando el paquete de `npm` `env-cmd` para las variables de entorno, creé el archivo `.env-cmdrc` y en el `package.json` pongo `env-cmd -e development,everywhere react-scripts start`, el problema que tengo es que al querer llamar las variables desde un componente lo escribo como:

```
const { *variable* } = process.env
```

Y me lo determina como `undefined`, también al momento de sacar en consola `process.env`, me saca lo siguiente:

```
NODE_ENV: "development"

PUBLIC_URL: ""
```

Solo me saca eso pero no todas las variables que tengo en ese archivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás usando `create-react-app` para tu proyecto, las variables de entorno deben comenzar con `REACT_APP`.
Ejemplo: `REACT_APP_MI_VARIABLE_DE_ENTORNO`

Te remito a este enlace de la documentación oficial que puede arrojarte algo más de luz sobre esto: [Documentación Oficial](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas *create-react-app* tienes que generar el archivo **`.env`** y empezar el nombre de cualquier variable con *REACT_APP*, ejemplo:

```
REACT_APP_MI_VARIABLE_DE_ENTORNO = "hy3rgher89h98g89reh"
```

Y utilizarlo directamente en tu código, ejemplo:

```
miVariamble : process.env.REACT_APP_MI_VARIABLE_DE_ENTORNO
```